# spring-cloud data flow shell not responding

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying some demos of spring cloud data flow according to [spring cloud demos](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_http_to_mysql_demo),but my scdf's shell doesn't work,neither the jar that i downloaded nor I debugged the shell in my IDEA,any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry you're having trouble with it. The problem description is not clear, though. Are you running it to connect to SCDF-server on CF/PCF? What's the behavior? Does it hang or terminate with a timeout error? See the [Reporting Issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#reporting-issues) guide for more details. If you could further elaborate on this by updating the post, that'd be helpful.

Comment: I was trying to run the demo of a spring-cloud dataflow on Windows, I pulled the src from github and trying to debug the server and shell in my IDEA, the server was ok, but the shell has no response to my input. it turns out i have to use powershell or command line for shell instead of IDEA or git shell.